# Rest clients for Java 5 and Spring 2.x

Tags: java, rest

I am stuck on Java 5 and Spring 2.x and need to call a rest api. Springs `RestTemplate` wasn't introduced until Spring 3 and it seems every other one I find requires Java 6 or 7.

Comment: You could try to go for apache HttpClient and do it low-level editing the urls. (Not sure if this makes much sense.)

Comment: @HassiaBiker do you know which version of HttpClient is compatible with Java 5? I am using 4.5.4 and getting the following error `Bad version number in .class file (unable to load class org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException)`